# Firebase Cloud Functions did not deploy properly with imported a module in subfolder

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a problem deploying Firebase Cloud Functions because it can't find the imported local module.

Here's the output of deploy command

```
> firebase deploy --only functions
> build
> tsc

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (69.03 KB) for uploading
i  scheduler: ensuring required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  pubsub: ensuring required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  scheduler: required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  pubsub: required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 12 function myFunctionName(us-central1)...
i  functions: scheduler job firebase-schedule-myFunctionName-us-central1 is up to date, no changes required
✔  functions[myFunctionName(us-central1)]: Successful upsert schedule operation. 

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        myFunctionName(us-central1)

To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only "functions:myFunctionName"

To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

I tried running `firebase --debug deploy` but it does not provide useful information and sends me to Logs in Firebase Console instead.

```
Provided module can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module './module/MyModule'
Could not load the function, shutting down.

Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging Function cannot be initialized.
```

As you can see in the code below `MyModule` is an imported local module.

---

Folder Structure (created using `firebase init`)

```
root
│   firebase.json
│   ...
│
└───functions
    │   package.json
    │   node_modules
    │   ...
    │
    └───src
        │   index.ts
        └───module
            │   MyModule.ts
```

**index.ts**

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { MyClass } from "./module/MyModule";

export const myFunctionName = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("every 5 minutes")
  .onRun(async () => {
    const myClass = new MyClass();
    const result = await myClass.doSomething();
    functions.logger.log("something has done!", result);
    return result;
  });
```

**./module/MyModule.ts**

```
export class MyClass {
  async doSomething() {
    // Do Something
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0",
    "googleapis": "^80.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

---

I have tried

- Test running the function locally (it does work!)
- Delete the function in Firebase Console before running the deploy command again
- Delete `node_modules` and run `npm install` again

Not sure what caused the problem. Why can't find a local module?

---

**Update**

I have tried to move `MyModule.ts` to the same level as `index.ts` and it does deploy!

So it will look like this:

```
root
│   firebase.json
│   ...
│
└───functions
    │   package.json
    │   node_modules
    │   ...
    │
    └───src
        │   index.ts
        │   MyModule.ts
```

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { MyClass } from "./MyModule"; // Updated import

export const myFunctionName = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("every 5 minutes")
  .onRun(async () => {
    const myClass = new MyClass();
    const result = await myClass.doSomething();
    functions.logger.log("something has done!", result);
    return result;
  });
```

But it still bothers me why can't import a module from a subfolder? Because there's a lot of files in my project and I want to organize them.

Comment: Deploying your code (with the `module` folder) on one of my test environments does work. What happens if you update the SDKs to the latest versions, by running the following in the `functions` folder: `npm install firebase-functions@latest --save` and `npm install firebase-admin@latest --save-exact`?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec `firebase-admin` updated to `9.10.0` and `firebase-functions` to `^3.14.1`. But after running `firebase deploy` it produces the same results. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I noticed that I have 2 functions both have similar implementation but importing a different module and only 1 function causes a deployment error.

And then I remembered that I have recently renamed the problematic module from  `myModule.ts` to `MyModule.ts` but Visual Studio Code still sees it as `myModule.ts` but the code still runs (locally) so I ignored it.

If you think your problem is similar to mine you can do the following.

- Rename the problematic file to something else.
- (If you want to keep the name) Delete your repository (locally) and clone it again.

Comment: I'm not sure what this problem is called (caching?). If you do please tell me. I've never encountered a problem like this before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem mine was fixed by simply running:

```
firebase deploy --only "functions:FunctionNameHere"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).